# Flutter : external barcode scanner continuous

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode-scanner

I am developing  a flutter application with below process

1. scan number (external Bluetooth barcode scanner)
2. upload barcode data
3. repeat 1,2 step c

I could able to scan and upload the first data. then I cleared the text. but i could not place the cursor at the _text controller.

I dont want to press the text field every time before scan the textfield.

```
TextField(
                controller: _text,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                onSubmitted: (value) {
                  print(submit online using function");
                  _text.clear();
                  _text.selection= TextSelection.collapsed(offset: -1);

                },
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  hintText: 'Enter ID',
                  labelText: 'Enter ID',
                ),
                autofocus: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: what plugin are you using to get data from the external barcode scanner?

Comment: we don't use any plugins for the external barcode scanners. Android detects as some keyboard.

Comment: oh, I can't even manage to connect the device via bluetooth, would you mind sharing the code to connect the scanner with your flutter app?

Comment: Is the device connected physically to the phone?

Comment: If you have a device with a USB you can connect via OTG. if BT, Just pair it. it will work. the below code(mokth) will just work fine.  if the continues is too fast, just increase the time( for that, the manufacturer would give a settings barcode ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   TextFormField(
          enabled: true,
          autofocus: true,
          autocorrect: false,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          focusNode: focusBarCode,
          onFieldSubmitted: (val) {
            print(val); // the scan value
            //process the val
            barCodecontroller.text =""; // set to blank again
            focusBarCode.requestFocus();//set focus again, so u can 
                                        //scan again
       `enter code here`},
       controller: barCodecontroller,
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

the external bar code scanner works like this:
The very first field on your UI will get clicked or what so ever..so make sure you place the field in your layout at the top...so when the barcode data enters the field all you have to do is clear the field and reset the focus on the very on the field(edittext)..
it is more advisable to use edit text in these cases.Also try to use looper with delay upto 1.5 secs to clear the text in edit text.

```
// Define the TextEditingController
final TextEditingController barcodeTextController = TextEditingController();

EditText(
  autofocus: true,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  focusNode: focusBarCode,
  onSubmitted: (val) async {
    print(val); // the scan value
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1500)); // Delay for 1.5 seconds
    barCodeController.clear(); // Clear the text
    focusBarCode.requestFocus(); // Set focus again for the next scan
  },
  controller: barCodeController,
),
```